# Refer one column to another of different tables using SqlAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have the following scenario,

1. I need to insert to a table(table1) which have primary key of type 'serial'.
2. Now I need to insert to another table(table2) which contains the primary key of table1 as foreign key.
3. Now both inserts to be take place within the same transaction and the generated primary key should be refereed in table2

Let us show what I tried

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table1'
    table1id= Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    table2id= Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table1.table1id'))
    name = Column(String)
#
table1 = Table1(name='abc')
table2 = Table2(table2id=table1.table1id)
session.add(table1)
session.add(table2 )
session.commit()
```

When I ran this code table1id is inserted as 15 in table1, 
but it is refered as 'null' in table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a model object in Python it is not yet flushed to the DB. In case of a serial column the DB is responsible for generating the new value, and so it is just `None` before generation. In the statement

```
table2 = Table2(table2id=table1.table1id)
```

you simply read that `None` and pass it as the keyword argument *table2id*. In order to obtain a value you need to [flush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#flushing) the changes to the database, so you should reorder your operations a bit:

```
table1 = Table1(name='abc')
session.add(table1)
# Flush the changes to the DB
session.flush()
table2 = Table2(table2id=table1.table1id)
session.add(table2)
session.commit()
```

SQLAlchemy could also perform most of this for you more or less automatically, if you'd define the [relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationships.html) between table 1 and 2, or if this is actually an [inheritance hierarchy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html).

Comment: Thank you so much..

Comment: But I have one query when the second insertion fails whether the first insertion rollbacks?

Comment: A flush is not a commit. It just sends the unsent changes in the current SQLA session to the database (issues inserts etc.). Normally SQLA handles flushing behind the scenes with autoflush, but in cases like these you have to be explicit.

Comment: I checked it.. It's roll-backing. Thank you once again.